# I don't think I'd have or had

Tags: grammar

If he hadn't I don't think I'd have ever watched Drive!

or

If he hadn't I don't think I'd had ever watched Drive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If he hadn't I don't think I'd have ever watched Drive!" is fine. "If he hadn't I don't think I'd had ever watched Drive!" is not possible--the contraction "I'd" equals "I would," and there is no proper context to say "I would had done" something.

*If I hadn't owned a car, I would not have driven to work. 
If he hadn't painted the fence, it would have looked much better.
If he hadn't, I don't think I'd have ever watched Drive [either]!*

Comment: thx for the quickie, 10/10 would post again. .)